# How create mac or windows app with React native

Tags: windows, macos, react-native

I create app for mobile and tablet. Can i create mac or windows app with the same code.
In Xcode we have target device iPhone, iPad and mac. Is it possible to create an application for the same code for mobile and desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate windows or windows app using react-native.

You could use [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) in order to run react-native components in a website (accessible from mac and pc).